# Prevent beforeunload function from executing if submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that gives a warning to the user if they are exiting the page when the `$('.article_div textarea')` form field is populated.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event) {
    var unsaved = "Are you sure you want to exit?";
    var text = $('.article_div textarea').val();
    if (text.length > 0){
        return unsaved;
    }
});
```

However, I would like to prevent this popup from executing when they click the submit button to the actual form.

How can I ammend the function to account for this? The element of the submit button is

`$('button.submit_post')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a boolean which gets positive when you click on submit Or remove the event of unload when clicked. The code will be as follows:

```
var isSubmitClicked = false;
$('button .submit_post').on("click",onClick);
function onClick(e){
   isSubmitClicked = true;
}
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event) {
   if(isSubmitClicked){
     isSubmitClicked = false;
     return;
   }
   // Rest of your method.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about binding a event handler to the submit event instead of the submit button element?
Maybe like this:

```
var submitted = false;
$('form').on("submit", function() {
   submitted = true;
   console.log('submitted');
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event) {
   if(submitted){
     submitted = false;
     console.log('aborted because of submit');
     return;
   }
   console.log('rest of code');
   // Rest of your method.
});
```